# Can I remove the OS X partition from a dual-boot MacBook Pro?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, macbook-pro

I am wondering if you can remove the Mac OS X partition to give the whole HDD to Ubuntu. Will it stop my computer from booting up? or will it work flawlessly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a MacBook which is solely installed as Ubuntu. It works fine. I did this from scratch, but I don't think just removing the single main OS X partition will stop your system working. Single boot Ubuntu on a Mac is described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Single-Boot%3a_Ubuntu_Only).